# How to speed up a NOT IN query?

Tags: mysql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT images.id from images WHERE images.id NOT IN
(
    SELECT
        temp.target_id

    FROM (
        SELECT
            images_user_groups.images_id AS target_id,
            images_user_groups.user_groups_id AS source_id

        FROM
            images_user_groups
    ) AS temp

        INNER JOIN
        user_groups ON user_groups.id = temp.source_id
    INNER JOIN
        images ON images.id = temp.target_id
    WHERE
        user_groups.description LIKE "%Freigabe ins Presseportal%"
    GROUP BY
        temp.target_id
)
```

It runs, but it goes very slowly -- 5 minutes and counting as I write this. (The subquery that I'm running a `NOT IN` on returns 36,000 rows, and I assume that the parent query is taking time to check every one of the 38,000 entries in the `images` table against those 36,000 rows.)

Is there a way I can speed this query up?

Comment: Have you tried this query on latest version of MySQL 8.0 (8.0.17)?  It has support for so-called anti-join, which should improve performance of NOT IN subqueries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be a *lot* faster to write this as a `LEFT JOIN`, looking for `NULL` values in `user_groups` to indicate that the image was not in that group:

```
SELECT i.id 
FROM images i
JOIN images_user_groups iu ON iu.images_id = i.id
LEFT JOIN user_groups u ON u.id = iu.user_groups_id AND u.description LIKE "%Freigabe ins Presseportal%"
GROUP BY i.id
HAVING COUNT(u.id) = 0
```

The problem with `NOT IN` and `NOT EXISTS` is that the `WHERE` clause has to be evaluated for every row in `images`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This query results in 109,123 rows being selected, which is more rows than we have in the images table. (There are around 38,000 rows in the images table.) So something is wrong here.

Comment: @Patrickatwork sorry, didn't allow for multiple user groups per image. Please check my edit.

Comment: @Patrickatwork I'll be interested to know how much faster it is.

Comment: It runs almost instantaneously -- 0.01 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You can try in below way

```
SELECT images.id from images WHERE images.id NOT IN
(
    SELECT images_user_groups.images_id 
    FROM images_user_groups INNER JOIN user_groups ON user_groups.id = images_user_groups.user_groups_id
    inner join images ON images.id = images_user_groups.images_id
    WHERE user_groups.description LIKE "%Freigabe ins Presseportal%"
)A
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Of the three answers so far, this is the only one that seems to return correct results. I'm not sure why it got downvoted.